# regex to match numbers within carriage return and line feed

Tags: c++, regex, boost

It is matching everything between \r\n. I want to only match digits between \r\n and replace with "".

```
regex: [^\r\n\d$\r\n]
Matching: 
     abc\r\n123\r\nabc\r\n
Doesnot match: 
     \r\n\r\n
     \r\nasaas\r\n
```

The regex says all the above are matching. 
This is useful in removing chunk lengths in packet data received from the socket. I want to remove the packet length that comes in the chunked packets and prepare a proper XML.

Comment: You should include all relevant information directly in your question. Links should be supplementary.

Comment: Since you have only one digit - it should not match at all

Comment: If you're implementing chunked transfer mode you should really be using a library that already does it for you, such as `HttpURLConnection`, Apache HTTP client, etc.

Comment: Using regex to strip out HTTP chunk length is not enough, as each chunk payload is followed by a CRLF. You would have to strip those out too, but you need the chunk lengths to do it correctly so you don't remove CRLFs that are inside the chunk payloads. Don't use regex to process HTTP data.

Comment: use this https://regex101.com/

Comment: @ShubhamAgrawal No, OP should most assuredly be fixing his wrong use of HTTP, not be using regex.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

From a pure regex standpoint to isolate numbers on lines by themselves: I think you want this:

```
(\n\d+\n)|(^\d+\n)|(\n\d+$)
```

As a C++ string: `"(\\n\\d+\\n)|(^\\d+\\n)|(\\n\\d+$)"` or simply `R"((\n\d+\n)|(^\d+\n)|(\n\d+$))"`

**Update**. As others have noted, regex might not be the most appropriate tool for parsing an HTTP stream.  But from a regex perspective, I'll stand by this answer.

Comment: Wait what. Do regex libaries unconditionally treat line ends special? Reason #42953 to stay away from regex (FWIW, [I don't think that's true](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7088761318d3d9fb))

Comment: Is `^\d` even a thing without `[]`?